# Apple Maps WMS URL

Tags: wms, url, apple

Can anyone tell me what the URL for Apple Maps WMS/WMTS is please?

I have tried http://maps.apple.com/ using Add WMS/WMTS Layer in QGIS, but this does not work.

Comment: Are you sure that Apple Maps offers WMS or WMTS Service?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580887/example-of-apple-maps-url-to-find-the-directions-to-certain-coordinates would suggest no WMS is available

Comment: OK thanks.  I was asking as apple maps satellite/ariel imagery is much superior to Google for UK coverage.  What is the WMS or WMTS that gives the best resolution satellite/ariel imagery for the UK?

Comment: You could look at using the QuickMapServices plugin https://umar-yusuf.blogspot.com/2016/10/background-maps-in-qgis.html