# Can Apple Maps be added to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, basemap

I'm using QGIS 3.16. I noticed that Apple Maps has satellite images that I would like to use as a basemap.

Can Apple Maps be added to QGIS?

Apple Maps on [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=New%20Zealand&ia=web&iaxm=maps&strict_bbox=0&bbox=53.22111449847817%2C-2.991093308789061%2C50.02539978020606%2C5.358516066210939)

Apple Maps on [Satellites Pro](https://satellites.pro/New_Zealand_map#-42.948381,173.562012,6)

Comment: It does not appear to be possible to add Apple Maps to QGIS.  See here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317986/apple-maps-wms-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit complicated solution: install and run nginx web server with tiles+token from DuckDuckGo:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMZiX9VhZPc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).